# assigning job roles based on partial match

Tags: excel, vba

i have job roles listed in a column and have another file which has job role/code (117 in total). i want to write excel macro which will perfrom partial or exact match search and assign job role/code from the list. there are more than 1 match, it should assign all the possible matches in the same row for that entry

here is the line of code. can someone modify it so that it could perform partial match and assign all the job role and code possible matches

```vb
Sub AssignJobRoles()
    Dim listFile As Workbook
    Dim listSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dblistFile As Workbook
    Dim dbSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dbLastRow As Long
    Dim dbCell As Range
    Dim listCell As Range
    
    Dim listFilePath As String
    listFilePath = "C:\Users\SumeetKopra\OneDrive - CETAS Healthcare\SUMEET\list-file.xlsx" 
    Dim listSheetName As String
    listSheetName = "Sheet1" 
    
    Set listFile = Workbooks.Open(listFilePath)
    
    Dim listRange As Range
    Set listSheet = listFile.Sheets(listSheetName)
    Set listRange = listSheet.Range("A1:B117") 
    Dim dbFilePath As String
    dbFilePath = "C:\Users\SumeetKopra\OneDrive - CETAS Healthcare\SUMEET\job-role.xlsx" 
    

    Dim dbSheetName As String
    dbSheetName = "Sheet2" 
    

    Set dblistFile = Workbooks.Open(dbFilePath)
    Set dbSheet = dblistFile.Sheets(dbSheetName)
    
  
    dbLastRow = dbSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
  
    For Each dbCell In dbSheet.Range("B2:B" & dbLastRow)
        Dim matchedCells As Range
        Set matchedCells = Nothing
        
     
        For Each listCell In listRange.Columns(2).Cells
            ' Check if there is a partial match
            If dbCell.Value Like "*" & listCell.Value & "*" Then
                If matchedCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set matchedCells = listCell
                Else
                    Set matchedCells = Union(matchedCells, listCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next listCell
        
     
        If Not matchedCells Is Nothing Then
            Dim matchCount As Long
            matchCount = matchedCells.Cells.Count
            
            Dim jobCodeArray() As Variant
            Dim jobTitleArray() As Variant
            ReDim jobCodeArray(1 To matchCount)
            ReDim jobTitleArray(1 To matchCount)
            
            Dim i As Long
            i = 1
            
            Dim matchCell As Range
            For Each matchCell In matchedCells
                jobCodeArray(i) = matchCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                jobTitleArray(i) = matchCell.Value
                i = i + 1
            Next matchCell
            
            dbCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(matchCount).Value = Application.Transpose(jobCodeArray) 
            dbCell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(matchCount).Value = Application.Transpose(jobTitleArray)

        Else
            dbCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" ' No match found, clear the Job Role Code
            dbCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" ' No match found, clear the Job Role Title
        End If
    Next dbCell
    
    listFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
    dblistFile.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

explained in the previous screen